# "smile" classifiers in Google Earth Engine

Tags: classification, google-earth-engine

What are the "smile" type classifiers in Google Earth Engine API? I see for example ee.classifier.NaiveBayes and ee.classifier.SmileNaiveBayes with exactly the same description, and I couldn't find anything else on the net about the "smile" thing.

Comment: See [SMILE classifiers/regressors in Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/368763)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently they are to improve the 'performance and stability'. The old classifiers are going to be removed eventually. This is all according to the GEE Dev team.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/jXSgqCerhbs/sZOT5T2eAwAJ

The actual GEE site has no explanation about this that I could find. This is what the GEE Google Group announcement says.

> Greetings Earth Engine developers!
>
> As part of our ongoing efforts to improve Earth Engine, we will be
>   migrating classifiers to a new system.
>
> The new versions of classifiers are:
>
> - ee.Classifier.smileCart replaces ee.Classifier.cart.
> - ee.Classifer.smileRandomForest replaces ee.Classifier.randomForest.
> - ee.Classifier.smileNaiveBayes replaces ee.Classifer.naiveBayes.
> - ee.Classifer.libsvm replaces ee.Classifier.svm.
>
> In many cases, the new versions have the same parameter sets as the
>   old versions, though for some there are differences. We expect that
>   performance and stability of the new versions should be better than
>   the old versions.
>
> The new versions of the CART and RandomForest classifiers allow access
>   (via explain()) to more data than the old versions, including variable
>   importance. Note that smileNaiveBayes truncates its inputs to integers
>   (the fractional part is lost). If this is an issue, you may find that
>   scaling the input values (e.g. by 10000) gives good results.
>
> You should begin to migrate all code that uses the old classifiers to
>   their new equivalents. In the future, the old classifiers will be
>   removed. To avoid any break in service when those classifiers are
>   eventually removed, please update to the new classifiers. If you have
>   trouble with the smile transition, please post questions here.
>
> The Google Earth Engine Team

Answer (score 0):

Layer 1: Layer error: Classifier.cart: This classifier has been removed.  For more information see: http://goo.gle/deprecated-classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

These functions use the [Statistical Machine Learning and Intelligence Model java library](https://haifengl.github.io/) - that's what SMILE stands for. The SMILE functions are more computationally efficient than the older depreciated versions.